# Can't get correct values for touch.rotationAngle or touch.force on Surface Pro 4

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event, surface-pro

I am testing a project on my Surface Pro 4 and I am using the [Touch interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) in javascript. According to MDN, the `rotationAngle` and `force` properties should return [0 - 90] and [0.0 - 1.0] respectively.

But no matter how I touch the display, I get fixed values for either of them. In Chrome (81) it is always **0** and **0.5**. In Firefox (76), **0** and **0** are returned.

The code is simple:

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) {
    // Prevent the mouse click
    evt.preventDefault();

    //-- Log the touch information
    var touch = evt.changedTouches.item(0);

    console.log(touch.radiusX);
    console.log(touch.radiusY);

    console.log(touch.rotationAngle);
    console.log(touch.force);

});
```

Now, about the `force` property, MDN specifies that if the value is unknown for some reason (e.g. the device doesn't support it), [0.0 is returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/force). But nothing is mentioned about a constant 0.5 for this property or 0 for the `rotationAngle`.

Am I missing something? Or does the Surface Pro 4 indeed not support these values and I can not do anything about it?

Answer (score 1):

The `touch.force` property is not supported on Surface devices. This is because the Surface line of devices does not have a pressure sensor, which is required to measure the force of a touch. The `touch.force` property can only be used on devices that have a pressure sensor, such as the iPhone, iPad, and some Android devices.

If you are trying to use the `touch.force` property on a Surface device, you will need to use a different method to measure the force of a touch, such as using a stylus or a pressure-sensitive keyboard.

I've tried on some big-screen devices with Windows system installed, still got the same result.